# how to use ng-repeat in partial html files using angular routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following code used to be part of my main html file but I decided to split the app, into partials and then render it but I am stuck now and don't know how to repeat the render the code any more.

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="TimeSlotController as calendar" >
 <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 timeblock" ng-repeat="slots in calendar.timeslot" ng-click="calendar.selectTimeSlot(slots.time)">
    <h3 class="event-type-name">[[ slots.time]] Hour Appointment</h3>
    <div class="description mts">[[slots.description]]</div>
    <div class="cost"><i class="fa fa-euro"></i> [[slots.cost ]]</div>
 </div>
```

This is how my controller looks like right now

```
app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

    $routeProvider
                .when('/timeslot', {
                    controller: 'TimeSlotController as timerange',
                    templateUrl:'/views/timeslot.html'
                })
                .when('/calendar', {
                    controller: 'CalendarController',
                    templateUrl:'/views/calendar.html'
                })
                .when('/mail', {
                    controller: "MailController",
                    templateUrl: '/views/mail.html'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirecTo: '/timeslot'
                });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                       enabled: true,
                       requireBase: false
                     });        


});


app.controller("TimeSlotController", function($rootScope, $location, $scope) {

    $scope.timeslot = [
       {
        time:1,
        description: "Welcome to my scheduling page. Please follow the instructions to add an event to my calendar.",
        cost: "10"
      },
       {
        time:2,
        description: "Welcome to my scheduling page. Please follow the instructions to add an event to my calendar.",
        cost: "20"
      },
       {
        time:4,
        description: "Welcome to my scheduling page. Please follow the instructions to add an event to my calendar.",
        cost: "10"
      },
      {
        time:6,
        description: "Here lies 3",
        cost: "10"
      }
    ];

    console.log($scope.timeslot);

    $scope.selectTimeSlot = function(timeslot) {

        $rootScope.timeSlot = timeslot;

        console.log($rootScope.timeSlot);

        $location.path('/calendar');
    }

});
```

How do I use ng-repeat in such file types ? I looked around a little but couldn't find exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: do you have a plunker? Anyway, I noticed you are using `calendar.` in HTML in order to qualify the scope variables. Try without it, letting angular pick it up automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ng-repeat="slots in timeslot"
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ImdmHlpevzO6FL2fe2EP?p=preview

As Dinesh said, remove calendar when you're specifying the controller. Unless you're doing something more complicated that we don't know about, Angular is smart enough to know which controller you're trying to use.

Comment: Thanks, that worked; I am still confused on how to debug such a thing in the future; any tips ?

Comment: Use binding aggressively in development and testing, and start from the top.  In this case, putting {{calendar.timeslot}} in the HTML rendered nothing, so I knew we had a problem there.  Changing it to {{timeslot}} brought up the entire timeslot array (obviously not what you want to end up there, but it shows that you have gotten that array clear through to the DOM.  A good sign!)  Once you have the parent object in the DOM, ng-repeating it is fairly easy.

Hope that helps!